# How to Enumerate a Table Sequentially

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to know how it is possible to enumerate a table sequentially and to save this value into some kind of variable so this value can be selected in another template. 
Each time the template table is called, the variable has to be incremented (the first value of the "counter" has to be 1).

```
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
           <title>Tables.</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/> 
           <!-- apply more templates -->   
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">    
    <center>        
        <b>Table **ENUMERATION OF THE TABLE** - </b><xsl:value-of select="title"/>                                                          
    </center>
    <br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- more templates -->
```

Input (XML):

```
<table id="table1">
<title>Title.</title>
<br/>
</table>

<table id="table2">
<title>Title.</title>
<br/>
</table>
```

Output (HTML):
**Table 1** - Title.
**Table 2** - Title.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of the input and the required output?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Uptaded!

Comment: I meant show us a minimal, but complete input that has at least two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not a good one. If your input looks something like:

```
<root>
    <table id="table1">
        <title>Title 1</title>
    </table>
    <not-table/>    
    <table id="table2">
        <title>Title 2</title>
    </table>
    <not-table/>    
    <table id="table3">
        <title>Title 3</title>
    </table>
</root>
```

then applying:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <center>        
        <b>Table <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> - </b>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>                                                          
    </center>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

will result in:

```
<root>
   <center>
      <b>Table 1 - </b>Title 1</center>
   <br/>
   <center>
      <b>Table 2 - </b>Title 2</center>
   <br/>
   <center>
      <b>Table 3 - </b>Title 3</center>
   <br/>
</root>
```

Comment: Is it possible to save this value into some kind of variable? And to specify to use position() only for the elements table? Because the enumeration isn't working correctly. The enumeration is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and post enough code (XML + XSLT) for us to reproduce the problem. The enumeration is NOT wrong when using my code - see: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMd

Comment: I don't see anything new.

Comment: @Ariana - It's probably because you're not applying templates only to `table`. Try using Michael's answer but replace `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` with `<xsl:number/>`.

Comment: @DanielHaley That can't hurt - but I took `<xsl:template match="table">` from the original question.

Comment: I saw that too, but the only way I can get your code to fail (+1) is by modifying the apply-templates. I thought that the actual code might be different.